# Maximal subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ w.r.t. the property that $1\not\in G$ contains a unique prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, maximal-subgroup

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a group under addition. Suppose that $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ which is maximal w.r.t. the property that $1\not\in G$. Show that there is a unique prime number $p$ such that $p\in G$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that there are two different prime numbers $p,p'\in G$. Then $1 = pm+p'n\in G$ (for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, Bézout).

So, if there is such a prime number, then it is necessarily unique. But how do I show that it exists? This question is given in a logic course (in fact, I had to prove the existence of the subgroup $G$ as above using Zorn's Lemma), so I don't think that I will have to use complicated algebra facts.

The subgroup $G$ is infinite, since, for example, $2\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies this property and $G$ is maximal (so $G\ge 2\mathbb{Z})$. Are $p\mathbb{Z}, p$ prime, the only subgroups satisfying this property? In that case, there always a unique prime $p$ in each $p\mathbb{Z}$, proving the statement.

Thanks.

Comment: $2\mathbb Z$ is not maximal in $\mathbb R$ (add $\pi$ to the group)

Comment: You can consider $H=G\cap \mathbb{Z}$. If this is empty, then you can make $G$ larger by considering the group generated by $G$ and $2$. This larger group wouldn't contain $1$, since otherwise $G$ would contain an odd integer contradicting that the intersection was empty. If $H$ is non-empty, then it is a subgroup of $Z$. If its minimum positive element is non prime, we can enlarge again the group by one of the prime divisors of this element.

Comment: Also, just because $G$ is maximal does not mean that $G \geq 2 \mathbb{Z}$. For example, $G$ might contain $3$ and then by your reasoning before it cannot contain $2$.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, a subgroup maximal for a property does *not* have to contain every other subgroup fitting that property. In a partially ordered set $(X, <)$, an element $m$ is maximal when $x < m$ for all $x$ *that are comparable* to $m$.  For instance, when you partially order the proper subgroups of $\mathbf Z$ by containment, the maximal elements are $p\mathbf Z$ for prime $p$, so there are lots of maximal elements. That $3\mathbf Z$ is maximal does not mean $2\mathbf Z \subset 3\mathbf Z$ since $2\mathbf Z$ and $3\mathbf Z$ aren't comparable (neither contains the other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint 1:** If $G \cap \mathbb Z = \{ 0 \}$, define $G'= \langle G, 2 \rangle$ to be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $2$ and $G$. Show that $G'$ is a larger group which does not contain 1, contradicting the maximality.

**Hint 2:** You know that $H:= G \cap \mathbb Z \neq \{0\}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ we have $H= n \mathbb Z$.

Show that if $p$ is a prime, $p\mid n$, then $G'=\langle G, p \rangle$ is also a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ which does not contain 1. Use maximality.

Comment: An intersection of subgroups is not going to be $\emptyset$. You meant to say the subgroup is $\{0\}$ (or not).

Comment: @KCd Yes, fixed. Thank you.